# htaccess rules denied access to unique address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a server where i host several websites. Some of them got a unique address and others i just browse to the subfolder of the server.

something like this:

www.maindomain.be ( subfolders /website1 /website2 /website3 ... )

and i have some unique names point to /website1 and /website2... www.website1.org and www.website2.org

I needed to redirect a domainA to a subfolder on my maindomain so i added some htaccess rules to make it point to the right subfolder but now if i surf to www.website1.org and www.website2.org i got an "Internal Server Error". If i add some htaccess rules for website1 and 2 i can access them but it would show the maindomain url and not the unique address...

I used these rules to redirect the domainA to the subfolder on my server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainA\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com/website3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can i add something to make the other websites still available from their unique address www.website1.org / www.website2.org ?

Comment: _“i got an "Internal Server Error"”_ – well then go check your server’s error log.

Comment: "/var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here
"

Answer (score 0):

> /var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

This means your server config isn't allowing the `FILEINFO` override. So in your vhost config, where you see possible the line:

```
AllowOverride None
```

in the context of the directory/document root of your server. It needs to be at least:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

or

```
AllowOverride All
```